# Flex alternatives which outputs html

Tags: html, apache-flex

I am currently using Flex to create large web applications which outputs swf file. But now I want to create same applications by different platforms which will output as html.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an html web application framework you could try [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) or [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/).

Comment: you can add Dart to the list, the language is similar to AS3 because  it has types and you can create components like in Flex

Comment: I think Dart is only good if you're already a good Javascript programmer. I don't recommend it.

Comment: why? did you had issues and had to check the generated JS ?  I did not used Dart in large projects so I want to know your experience if you did

Comment: My problem is not with Dart itself, but with the fact if you need to use a Javascript library you need to know Javascript to effectly use it if there's no Dart port, and most certainly there's no port.

In my onpinion, the effort of learning 2 languages is not worth it - mainly because Javascript will have classes in the future, which is Dart's strongest feature.